# Simulate shell environment available to GUI Apps?

Tags: terminal, applications, applescript, bash, script

I'm testing some scripts which are destined for use inside various GUI Apps, either as direct shell calls or as part of an AppleScript `do shell script` call.  I know from experience that the shell which an App gets is nothing like what I get by default when starting Terminal, so I'd like to figure out a way to simulate the shell that an App gets so that I can debug the scripts knowing that they are behaving as I should expect them to behave in their final expected use environment.

So, how to I open an Terminal (or modify one which is already open) so that it behaves like the shell that a GUI App has access to?

Answer (score 2):

First, let me solve the problem of a GUI app not providing the same environment as a terminal session to a bash script.

The differences are because of your bash profile, so you can have exactly the same in a GUI shell script by using the `source` command. Put the line `source /Users/<username>/.bash_profile` (replacing `<username>` with your short name) at the top of your bash script and you will have the same environment in the script when run inside a GUI app as in your shell session.

To get a shell without running your profile in [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) (I couldn't get it to work in Terrminal):

- Open to Terminal->Preferences
- Go to the Profiles pane
- Duplicate your default profile
- In "General"
- Change the name of the new profile to "No Profile"
- Set the shortcut key to Control-Command-A
- Click on "Command"
- Set the command to `/bin/bash -norc`
- Close the Preferences

Now Control-Command-A will open a session exactly the same as a GUI app would get - everything set to the `bash` default.

Comment: Sourcing in the profile does not solve all the problems.  GUI apps, for instance, do not read-in modifcations to PATH from `/etc/paths.d/` the way Terminal does.  I think there might be some other environment variable issues too, but I haven't been able to nail them down yet.  Still, I'll look into iTerm2 and see how much closer that gets me to where I need to be.

Comment: The minor differences you have found are due to a GUI app not running `/etc/profile`. The only one of significance is the PATH, apologies for forgetting it, I explicitly set mine in my profile. The others are all terminal and Terminal related. Using the iTerm2 solution fixes all that, too.